# get attribute from children on 2000 products

Tags: magento

I'm using a script to generate a csv file for another site.
I am getting all products and on configurable ones I add in description some attributes.

Here is the code inside the function called on each configurable:

```
    $children_ids = $product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProductIds();

    foreach($children_ids as $child_id){
        $child = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($child_id);
        $attributeValue = $child->getAttributeText($attributeLabel);
        $child_qty = (int)$child->getStockItem()->getQty();
        $mage_size[$attributeValue] = $child_qty;
        $simple_qty += $child_qty;
    }
```

I noticed that on large amount of products somehow the output suddenly stop without getting all. I tested with and without this code. Without I get as expected.
I have set_time_limit(0);
But no clue why my script terminate before getting information from all products.
Any ideea whay may couse this behaviour?

Comment: Many things could cause such behaviour. My first two guesses would be `exception` or `out of memory`. Nothing in the Magento and PHP log files?

Comment: Nothing in logs. In my ignorance I tought time_limit would be enough. Once I added memory_limit to a high value it works.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a proper solution but works on my script.
I added

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');
```

and works fine. I know 512 is way too much but just to be sure and to prevent that behaviour in the future when will be more products.

Answer (score 0):

You would both have to increase the memory limit and PHP's execution time - magento is freakin' resource hungry.

I also generate product csv's with a custom script. I would recommend to run these kind of tasks from the command line.